# RequireJS - cannot load Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, requirejs

I am in the process of converting my app to use require.js, but I cannot seem to get Bootstrap to load. This is in outline what I'm doing (the following assumes a simple flat directory structure, with no subdirectories):

*main.js*

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    "jquery": "jquery-1.12.4.min",
    "bootstrap" : "bootstrap.min"
  },
  shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    }
  }
});

require(["jquery"], function($) {
  console.log($.fn);
});
```

*index.html*

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>RequireJS Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">File</a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Open...</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Save</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Save As...</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script data-main="./main" src="./require.js"></script>
</html>
```

My Bootstrap navbar dropdowns do not function, and indeed when I investigate the jQuery object itself in the console I see nothing attached from bootstrap.min.js. But I cannot see what I'm doing wrong. My real app also uses Backbone, and that gets loaded without issue. For that I use the following shim:

```
'backbone': {
  'deps': ['jquery', 'underscore'],
  'exports': 'Backbone'
}
```

But the shim for Bootstrap is just not working for me. Am I missing something obvious?

I am using the latest versions of requirejs, bootstrap and jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not shown any code that actually causes Bootstrap to be loaded. Change your initial `require` to:

```
require(["jquery", "bootstrap"], function($) {
  console.log($.fn);
});
```

In case this is where your confusion originates: your `shim` says "when you load `bootstrap`, load `jquery` first". It does not trigger the loading of `bootstrap`. You have to list `bootstrap` as a dependency to `require` or `define` for the loading to happen.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Indeed that was what confused me. I was under the impression that `requirejs.config` would just load everything just as in the case of a bunch of script tags. But I guess this is the 'asynchronous' bit of AMD, right?

Comment: `requirejs.config()` does not load anything unless you use the `deps` option at the *top level* to provide a list of modules to load. (This one is at the top level of the configuration. It is not the same as the `deps` inside individual `shim` values.) Note that the top level `deps` is *exactly* the same as doing `require(<value of deps>)` immediately after the `require.config` call.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clarification.